# How do I make tags different colors?

Tags: tumblr

On my [blog](https://balentay.tumblr.com/)  I want specific tags to be different colors.  So say a post is tagged with #photo post I'd like it to be red.  #audio post might be blue, #quote post might be yellow and so on and so forth.

Unspecified tags would remain the default tag color.

When I do

```
.text_post {color:#ffffff;}
```

for example, it changes the text color and tag symbols, but not [the tags themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Khm.png)

I would appreciate any help on figuring this out!  I don't know much about coding unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The color doesn't change because the tags have their own colors applied to them separately. Basically what happens is you have a text_post class applied to the  tag, but then a later style overwrites this to apply a separate color to the tags of this (and presumably every other) category of posts.

First, make sure you find the spots in the code (if any) that assign colors to the tags, probably (but not necessarily) through the class `.tag.`

Something like `.text_post .tag [put your css styles here WITHOUT THE BRACKETS]` should then work, but do note that if your code applies a different class from "tag" (which is what the version currently live uses) to the tag links, this will not work. Note that links have separate states (`:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`) and you have to make sure they are all covered by the instruction for each class of posts, or they will revert to default, identical colors when clicked or visited (browser don,t usually have a `:hover` style by default).

Comment: This does work, but it's not quite what I want.  I don't want to affect all the tags on a certain type of post, I want to affect certain, specified tags themselves.  For instance, for [these tags](https://i.imgur.com/j3yFFbe.png) I'd want the first to always be gray when it gets tagged.  The second is just a comment and wouldn't have it's own specified color, and as such would be the default tag color.  The third one would be red

Comment: OH. My bad. [There you go](https://arqueete.tumblr.com/post/54284216514).